# Cannot redirect away from namespaced controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, namespaces

I have

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```

which inside, in on of the actions I have

```
    redirect_to controller: "profiles", action: "edit"
```

which is to profiles_controller which is not under Users namespace

it keeps redirecting to users/profiles

I could move it to be under that namespace.. but I prefer to fight the system..

How do I redirect away from the current namespace?